# How can I create a TFS 2010 Team Project using the SDK?

Tags: .net, tfs

I've heard that it's not possible, but I figured I'd ask here and get a definitive answer. Is there a way to use the Team Foundation Server 2010 SDK to programatically create a new project in a collection?

So far, all I've seen is to use this method of scripting the VS 2010 IDE: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010.aspx. Ugly.

I'm keeping my fingers crossed that there's a better way. Ideas?

Comment: I don't think I've seen anything in the .net TFS Object Model for project creation, but I may have missed it. VS is communicating with TFS over HTTP, so if nothing else you could capture the traffic with Fiddler, see what its doing, and then write your own little program to make the same calls.

Comment: @Tridus that's sketchy... especially with Microsoft. They change things under the hood all the time.

Comment: Why do you want to automate the creation of a team project? If you're creating team projects on a regular enough basis to want to be able to automate it, you're probably doing something drastically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead of the command line:

```
string log = @"C:\Builds\tfsLog.txt";
string settingsFilePath = @"C:\TeamProjects\TeamProjectSettings.xml";
var batchTeamProjectCreator = new BatchTeamProjectCreator();
var succes = batchTeamProjectCreator.BatchCreateTeamProject(settingsFilePath, out log);
```

you'll need to add a reference to this dll:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.dll`

**You will still need to use the xml, but its a bit more elegant.**

Hope this is what you where looking for. :)

Good luck,
Oshry

Answer (score 1):

I am working on this recently, and I find a best solution:

1. Install "Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools" within your VS2010 box.
2. Execute command:

> \Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\TFPT.exe createTeamProject /collection:http://vm-haitch:8080/tfs/TestCollection /TeamProject:Project1 /ProcessTemplate:"MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0" /SourceControl:New /log:C:\Temp\TFS\Auto\ /verbose /noreports /noportal

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I can't. The blog post mentioned in the question is the way to do it. There is a wrapper to that in the TFS PowerTools for 2010, but it does the same thing and the XML file creation is still necessary.