# Is it possible to create a new Team Project from Source Explorer in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are using Team Foundation Server 2010 for source control only. We don't really use the application lifecycle management aspects of it.

Therefore, we pretty much live in Source Explorer. What I find annoying is that I can't create a new project from there, but instead have to open Team Explorer and go through the wizard there to create a top level folder.

I'd like to know if there is someway to skip the Team Explorer step and just create a top level project quickly (default settings), preferably from Source Explorer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to achieve this via VStudio, I think you are out of luck. 

It's possible to construct programmatically a TeamProject, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099100/how-can-i-create-a-tfs-2010-team-project-using-the-sdk) if this fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe you can create a new team project from Source Control Explorer.

However, you can do it from the [command-line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010.aspx), or using the [power tool](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/e54a6674-e643-48a8-9e59-0f7d14b7f805).